# where to put application data and temp files on mac

Tags: java, macos

We have a Windows Java desktop application that creates some **configuration files** at `%APPDATA%` and creates **logs** at `%TEMP%` location. Now we are planning to release that desktop application for Mac OS X. We are facing following difficulties:

1. We do not want to keep application data within `.app` (file extension app) so please suggest where else we can keep our configuration files.
2. We do not want to keep temporary files at `%TEMP%` location in Mac OS X because Mac OS X automatically cleans the `%TEMP%` location as per schedule.

**So we do not want data lose from temp and do not want to keep data with in .app**. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Uhm ... if you don't want to lose some files then any kind of temp directory is not the correct place. The whole point of those directories is that any data in there is replaceable (this is also true for Windows!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We do not want to keep application data within .app (file extension app) so please suggest where else we can keep our configuration files.

Use [`Preference API`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html)

> We do not want to keep temporary files at %TEMP% location in MAC OS because MAC OS automatically clean %TEMP% location as per schedule.

Create a dir under `user.home` to keep temp data

Answer (score 5):

You should probably put the files under `/Library/Application Support/<your app>` or `~/Library/Application Support/<your app>`

> If the resources apply to all users
>   on the system, such as document
>   templates, place them in
>   `/Library/Application Support`. If the
>   resources are user-specific, such as
>   workspace configuration files, place
>   them in the current user’s
>   `~/Library/Application Support`
>   directory.

**Source:** [Determining Where to Store Your App-Specific Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Either `~/Library/Application Support` or `~/Library/Caches` come to mind. Use the APIs if possible.